# Where does Umbraco Contour store the contactform data in database

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am new to umbraco...i want to crate a contactus form so i created contactform with the help of contour as here no need to write any code... it's working fine, now where the data is going to store in the database table(tablename)

Answer (score 3):

Contour details are stored in the tables that start with 'UF' in umbraco database.
Table UFRecordsXml store the form data in xml fomat.

For More info:

http://our.umbraco.org/projects/umbraco-pro/contour/documentation/Developer/

http://umbraco.com/help-and-support/video-tutorials/umbraco-pro/contour/create-forms-without-coding.aspx